# What's the origin of the rhyme "My friend Billy had a ten foot willy"?

Tags: poetry, textual-history, oral-tradition

A simple rhyming song which I heard growing up and which still gets stuck in my head every so often:

> My friend Billy had a ten foot willy.
>   He stuck it through the neighbour's door. ***OR*** He showed it to the girl next door.
>   She thought it was a snake,
>   Hit it with a rake,
>   And now it's only four foot four.

A little searching on the internet has convinced me that this is a somewhat well-known ditty, at least in England, so not just made up by someone I knew.

**What is the origin of this song?** Where and when did it first appear, and is there any hint of an original author?

(I've found the same question asked on another forum, [Who Wrote The Naughty Rhyme "My Friend Billy Had a Ten Foot..."](https://forums.digitalspy.com/discussion/1978929/who-wrote-the-naughty-rhyme-my-friend-billy-had-a-ten-foot), but without any serious answers (the top answer "*My mate did. Yours sincerely, Billy.*" is absolutely hilarious and absolutely useless). I've also found an [article](http://www.newsbiscuit.com/2017/05/25/my-friend-billy-has-a-ten-foot-willy-nominated-for-award/) crediting it to one James "Nipper" Jenkins, but given that the same site has an article "*Pfizer cuts research into Alzheimer's, but can't remember why - more soon*", I'd consider it somewhat less than reliable.)

Comment: This is a pretty good time to start learning about folklore studies. This article is certainly relevant: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1499891 i also recommend the book *Folklore Matters*. And i definitely remember reading something by a colorist who researched this very rhyme.

Comment: All such verses are composed by a branch of [The Splendid Source](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v012n03_1957-03_PDF/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v012n03_1957-03_PDF#page/n79/mode/2up), the secret society which supplies the world with dirty jokes.

Comment: When and where did you first hear this song, and to what tune was it sung?

Comment: @user14111 I don't even remember how I first heard it; it's just one of those things I knew growing up (in England). My internet research shows that it goes back to the 1970s at least. I'm rubbish with tunes, but it's something like: "***My** friend **Bill**y had a **ten** foot **will**y. He **stuck** it through the **neigh**bour's **door**. She **thought** it was a **snake**, **Hit** it with a **rake**, And **now** it's only **four** foot **four**.*"

Comment: It's [*Old King Cole*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3mli_Z60DA), of course!

Comment: I heard it at school in King's Lynn, which puts it in the early 1960s at latest. Probably not original even then.

Comment: Tried the Opies? http://blogs.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/archivesandmanuscripts/2017/03/07/opie-archive/

Comment: @AE I've [cited their book](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=opie) a couple of times, but I don't actually have a copy of it - been relying on Google Books and such.

Comment: Iona Opie recorded the start in Salford 1975: https://sounds.bl.uk/Oral-history/Opie-collection-of-children-s-games-and-songs-/021M-C0898X0073XX-0100V0

Comment: Also Dorset 1975 https://sounds.bl.uk/Oral-history/Opie-collection-of-children-s-games-and-songs-/021M-C0898X0080XX-0200V0

Comment: See also the same question in Mythology & Folklore SE https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/3367/197

Comment: @b_jonas Yes, another user copied my question after failing (in now-deleted comments here) to browbeat me into deleting this question and re-posting it on Mythology.

Comment: Same rhyme also documented in Australia and New Zealand. See https://museumsvictoria.com.au/media/3835/play-and-folklore-issue44-nov2003.pdf , which refers to an interesting-looking paper if you can find it: Grugeon, Elizabeth. (1988). ‘Underground knowledge: What the Opies missed’, English in Education, Vol. 22, No. 2.